# Dutch Baby Disaster!

Tags: baking, pancakes

So I made these Dutch Babies this morning following the New York Times recipe and usually they puff up beautifully but today they didn't and were a disaster. What did I do wrong? I'm thinking to much flour perhaps??

[image: dutch baby]

3 eggs
½ cup flour
½ cup milk
1 tablespoon sugar
 Pinch of nutmeg
4 tablespoons butter

Comment: Is there an award for the best title?

Comment: It's going to help us a lot if you give us the recipe and what you may have done differently.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out after looking at the recipe as I was copying it to my question. I didn't add the milk!

[image: how they normally look]

Comment: Did you taste your disaster? Looks quite tasty though they might be chewy. That's not a bad thing.

Comment: I'm a perfectionist, if it doesn't look like a typical Dutch baby I won't try it lol

Comment: That's okay. I'm always willing to taste my mistakes if they look edible and semi-appealing. At times, I've discovered new ways to cook something or a new recipe. I was telling my son that I wished I had a nice big combination lab-kitchen (science being one of my passions) to work in but would really love to have a lab assistant/flunky to help and then clean up afterward! :D

Comment: I think I need to make some! I make popover often but never sweetened ones like these. They look very good!

Comment: I'm intrigued - how is a *Dutch baby* different from a *Yorkshire pudding*, which it very much resembles (in appearance at least)?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  the recipes are very similar but Dutch babies are sweet and you cook in butter not meat drippings 

Comment: I'm wondering about the legality of eating 'babies', don't we have laws against that sort of thing?